# Android jar directory

Tags: android, netbeans

I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError referencing jsoup. I have the jar in the libs directory, but there is no reference to my jar files in the Android Manifest file. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for adding external jar in your android project refer use theses posts:

[Adding external JARs to Android Projects in Netbeans](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Adding_external_JARs_to_Android_Projects_in_Netbeans_%28nbandroid_-_kenai%29)

[android: Adding external JAR file in to android](http://android:%20Adding%20external%20JAR%20file%20in%20to%20android)

as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057804/how-can-i-use-an-external-jar-in-an-android-project-in-netbeans) post :
The steps I took so far are:

1) Create the library project, with android.jar included to have access to Android classes (the library uses android.util.Log and other Android classes).

2) Compile the library as a jar.

3) Add the library's jar to the Android application (right-click on Libraries under the project node and add the jar).

Answer (score 1):

jsoup is external jar right?have you added this jar into you project?Select Build Path->configure build path->select libraries tab->add external Jars.You put jsoup in libs directory ,it still not link to your project until you add it as external jar.Sorry if i misunderstand your question.

Comment: How do I do this in Netbeans, I'm not seeing a reference to build path

Comment: oh, i'm not work on Netbeans, in eclipse you just right lick on your project. maybe you can get the answer from searching google of how to add external jars in netbeans.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are there, my Netbeans points to the libs directory, "Location of JAR Libraries" is pointing to my libs directory

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Simon writes in [this blog post:](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Adding_external_JARs_to_Android_Projects_in_Netbeans_%28nbandroid_-_kenai%29)

> A very annoying issue that I've noticed with the NBAndroid Netbeans
>   plugin, is that it doesn't know how to properly attach an external JAR
>   file to an Android Project. If you right-click on libraries (under
>   your project folder), and click on 'Add JAR/Folder', it will add a
>   reference to that library/JAR file, which it will recognize in the
>   code (detect all the classes, etc). The problem lies when you try to
>   compile the project - at that point, it doesn't actually add the JAR
>   to the project, which in turn gives you errors when running.
>
> It actually took me quite awhile to find a solution for this, and an
>   annoying one at that. In order to correct this, you'll have to open up
>   your build.xml file (which is under your project folder, but hidden in
>   the netbeans environment). I had to open up my file explorer (Finder
>   on my mac :-)), and go to the project folder and open it up from
>   there. Add the following bit under your import file tag:
>
> ```
> <target name="-pre-jar"> 
>   <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}"> 
>     <fileset dir="/path/to/your/jar/directory" /> 
>   </copy> 
> </target>
> ```
>
> So, if your JAR is in /home/bla/myjars/lala.jar then your path should
>   be "/home/bla/myjars".
>
> Now, try recompiling it and it should work fine.

Comment: what do I have to do to get pre-jar to run as part of the normal build?

Comment: I see it under build-xml but it is greyed out

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057804/how-can-i-use-an-external-jar-in-an-android-project-in-netbeans) similar SO question to get more clear. Because I'm generally using eclipse as my development IDE.

Comment: When I look at my project folder, a directory called ${build.classes.dir} is being created, and it has the jar file in it. How do I tell ant to put the jar inside the build?